# If $x,y,z\in[-1,1]$ and $1+2xyz\geq x^2+y^2+z^2$, then can we infer $1+2(xyz)^n\geq x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

This problem was in IMC 2010.

> Assuming $x,y,z\in [-1,1]$, suppose that
> $$1+2xyz\geqslant x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$
> Can we infer from this that $$1+2(xyz)^n\geqslant x^{2n} + y^{2n} + z^{2n}$$ for any positive integer $n$?

Comment: Seems true. But I can't prove it.

Comment: if $x=y=z=-1$ then $1+2 \cdot (-1)(-1)(-1)=1-2=-1 \leq (-1)^2+(-1)^2+(-1)^2=3$ so it's not true.

Answer (score 5):

We can assume that $ab\geq0$ because

if $ab<0$, $ac<0$ and $bc<0$ we get $a^2b^2c^2<0$, which is contradiction.

The condition gives $(1-a^2)(1-b^2)\geq(c-ab)^2$ and we need to prove that
$$\left(1-a^{2n}\right)\left(1-b^{2n}\right)\geq\left(c^n-a^nb^n\right)^2,$$
which is C-S:
$$\left(c^n-a^nb^n\right)^2=(c-ab)^2\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}c^i(ab)^{n-1-i}\right)^2\leq(c-ab)^2\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(ab)^{n-1-i}\right)^2\leq$$
$$\leq(1-a^2)(1-b^2)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{2i}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b^{2i}=\left(1-a^{2n}\right)\left(1-b^{2n}\right)$$
and we are done!